# Question about Variance Needs Help!

Tags: variance

I would love it if anyone can help me with this variance.
I have $R = 3X + 3Y$, $Q = 3X - 3Y$. Can I do: $\text{Var}(R + Q) = (\text{Var}(3X + 3Y + 3X - 3Y) = \text{Var}(6X) = 36* \text{Var}(X)$?
I think this is correct, however, I don't know the way to verify it.
Thank you so much!